# The setter 'setValue=' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to assign an input value into my model in order to use it in the API POST request. However, I keep getting the error:

> `setter was called on null when saving`

Model:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Discount {
  String value;

  Discount();

  set setValue(String value) { 
    this.value = value; 
  }
```

Dart Code:

```
                children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          initialValue: _invoiceFormData.discount?.value ?? '0.00',
                          inputFormatters: [_amountValidator],
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                            decimal: true,
                            signed: false,
                          ),
                          decoration: TextFormField.decoration(
                            labelText: Localizations.of(context)
                                .text('label_invoice_discount'),
                          ),
                          onChanged: (String value) {
                            setState(() {
                              discountTotal = value;
                        });   
                        },
                         onSaved: (value) => _invoiceFormData
                  .discount.setValue = value,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                          discountType = !discountType;
                          });
                        },                        
                     ),
                  ],
```

Log:

```
The setter 'setValue=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: setValue="10.00"
```

I tried to set `_invoiceFormData.discount.value = value` but it is still showing the same error.

Comment: Try setting an inital value for the 'value' variable. Something like empty strings

Comment: Try replacing   Discount(); with   Discount(this.value); and remove your "set setValue(String value) { 
    this.value = value; 
  }"

Answer (score 0):

use StatefulWidget class and

change this

```
onSaved: (value) => _invoiceFormData
          .discount.setValue = value,
```

to

```
onSaved: (value) => setState(() {
      onSaved: (value) => _invoiceFormData
          .discount.setValue = value,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log is saying that `_invoiceFormData.discount` is null when you are using the setter `setValue=`.

To resolve this, you first need to instantiate the field `discount` in your object named `_invoiceFormData`. For example, when you initialize this form data (maybe in your initState()), you should do `_invoiceFormData.discount = Discount();` then it will not be null anymore